# Lookup "not matched" vs Query "NOT IN"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, ssis

I am currently looking for ways to optimize an ETL process using SSIS 2010.

Unfortunately, I'm confused as to when/what is the best way to use these two.

Should I use look up data transformation and directs the flow to not matched or should I use select statement with not in clause then inserts it directly to destination?

**Using not matched**
 
 [image]

**Using Query with `NOT IN`**

[image]

Comment: If you are having a performance issue, SSIS lookups are killers. For large recordsets that are correctly indexed, a INSERT statement using NOT EXISTS is many magnitudes faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without doubt, the latter approach is definitely much faster. Anything in SSIS is much expensive operation that when done in SQL directly via query/SP.
Here's an [MSDN link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966529.aspx) which explains this

> Reduce your Estimated Row Size as much as possible by removing any
>   unnecessary columns and configuring data types correctly. Any
>   opportunity that you have to reduce the size of the source data set
>   before operations begin saves memory resources.

Less data in buffer means, more oppertunity for performance generally, but in this case you save a lot by skipping the Look Up transform completely.

Also an article from [SQLMag](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-integration-services/designing-ssis-packages-high-performance) says

> **Reduce the number of rows.** When working with a relational source, use
>   a WHERE clause to filter the data to the rows you need rather than
>   rely on a transformation in the pipeline to eliminate rows. When
>   working with large flat files, break up the source file where possible
>   and process the resulting files using sequential Data Flow Tasks to
>   minimize I/O contention.

You can also modify your query so that inner query is not run for each row, like below

```
/* Source Query with NOT IN clause */ 

SELECT ColumnValues 
FROM 
Table1 A (NOLOCK) LEFT JOIN Table2 B (NOLOCK) ON A.Col1 =B.Col1 
LEFT JOIN 
Table3 C (NOLOCK) ON c.Col1 =A.Col1
WHERE C.Col1 is NULL AND CRD NOT IN ('ALO', 'PM')
```